# Google Map centred on user's current location PLUS default location as a backup

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

My store locator is set to center on the user's current location, but how can I make it default to a location when the user doesn't allow his/her location to be known? The code in the else statement isn't working but I'm not sure why. Here is what I have:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

(function() {

  if(!!navigator.geolocation) {

      var map;

      var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

          var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

          map.setCenter(geolocate);

      });

  } else {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  }

  var panelDiv = document.getElementById('panel');

  var data = new MedicareDataSource;

  var view = new storeLocator.View(map, data, {
    geolocation: false,
    features: data.getFeatures()
  });

  new storeLocator.Panel(panelDiv, {
    view: view
  });

})();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Geolocation map by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33092631/geolocation-map-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the else isn't working because it is never executed (`!!navigator.geolocation` is true).  If `geolocation` is available, but encounters an error, the `error` function would be called, but you don't have one defined.

The getCurrentPosition method is defined as (from [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)):

> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success[, error[, options]])
> **Parameters**
> **success** - A callback function that takes a Position object as its sole input parameter.
> **error** - Optional - An optional callback function that takes a PositionError object as its sole input parameter.
> **options** - Optional - An optional PositionOptions object.

Add an error function to set the map's center:

```
function error(err) {
  console.log('ERROR('+err.code+'): '+err.message);
  if (map && map.setCenter) map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194))
};
```

Then add it to the `.getCurrentPosition` call:

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(geolocate);
  }, error);
```

[proof of concept fiddle (https: works)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gwcg8tfm/2/)
[proof of concept fiddle (http: fails due to non-secure origin)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gwcg8tfm/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function error(err) {
  console.log('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
  if (map && map.setCenter) map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194))
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {

  if (!!navigator.geolocation) {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocate = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(geolocate);
    }, error);

  } else {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```